# ajax POST allways o success no funcionan

Tags: php, ajax

He buscado preguntas similares, pero a pesar que hay varias, no creo que mi error se encuentre entre ellas, no consigo que funcione.

Estoy haciendo una llamada usando ajax:

```
eventReceive: function( info ) {
          var start = info.event.start.toISOString();
          var id = info.event.id;
          $.ajax({
            url:"calendaradd.php",
            type:"POST",
            data:{start:start, id:id},
             dataType: "json",
            success : function(){
             calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
             alert('Event Update');
            }
           })
      },
      });
```

el archivo php es como sigue:

```
<?php

//update.php
include_once 'Db.php';


$id = substr($_POST['id'], 30);
$id = strstr($id, '"', true);

$query = "UPDATE invoiceline SET ItemDate = '" . $_POST['start'] . "' WHERE ilid = " . $id;

$res = $DB->query($query); 
$data["message"]=true;
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

el problema es que no ejecuta el código de la función success. He probado enviando "1" en JSON, he probado enviando "true", no entiendo qué debo enviar. Quiero que esto se ejecute siempre, entonces probé con allways, pero tampoco funcionó

Answer (score 0):

buenas podrías cambiar tu ajax a este formato, así tienes el error type de la promersa,

```
        $.ajax({
          url:"calendaradd.php",
          method: 'POST',
          data:{start:start, id:id},
          async: false,
          dataType: 'JSON',
          success: function(respuesta) 
          {
            if(respuesta.message)
            {
                 calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
                 alert('Event Update');
            }
            
          },
          error: function() 
          {
             alert('Error tipo 500 o 400');
          }
        });
```

Comment: lo intenté, pero tampoco hace nada :(

Comment: estoy corriendo en XAMPP, ¡será que eso pueda ser el problema?

Comment: tenes el cdn de jquery ajax ?, no creo que sea alguna configuración del XAMPP, puebra agregando

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

Comment: agregué esa línea y tampoco ejecuta el success :(

Comment: ok, ¿cómo hago para cerrar esta pregunta?, resulta que se me ocurrió remover la línea calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents'); y ejecutó el alert, o sea que el problema no es en ajax

Comment: añade tu solución como respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

por lo visto el problema no está en ajax, sino en el manejo del calendario en sí. Al eliminar la línea calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents'); me da el mensaje de forma correcta